# Why Isn't The Partial File Automatically Created?

Tags: railstutorial.org

Getting through Michael Hartl's tutorial great; I've encountered a few snags along the way but nonetheless, it's working out better than I expected.

My question, is regarding the partial file. In the tutorial if I have read correctly, chapter 5- it advises to edit the 'application.html.erb' file with...

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>'
```

The tutorial then says if this line worked I should find a file called 'app/views/layouts/_shim.html.erb' and I cannot find it, thus, it was not automatically created, further not allowing me to pull up the referring static page in my browser (which may or may not be related).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Of course, to get the partial to work, we have to fill it with some content; in the case of the shim partial, this is just the three lines of shim code from [Listing 5.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#code-layout_new_structure); the result appears in [Listing 5.10](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#code-stylesheets_partial).

So yes. You have to create partial file by yourself and fill it with proper content. In case you code editor doesn't support partial extraction.

*For example*:

Using **rails.vim** plugin for VIM there is the possibility to extract selected lines into partial by using `Rextract <partial_name>` command. Which creates new file, moves selected lines into it and replace selected lines from source file with `<%= render :partial => '<partial_name>' %>`